# How to select a certain number of random values with odi 12 c?

Tags: random, oracle-data-integrator

How can I make the following query work in odi 12c?

I need your support on which components I need to use and how.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table name
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum <= n;
```

I used sort component but it gives me the warning in this image.

[image: 1]

Comment: What is the high level requirement you are trying to achieve? What is `n` supposed to be? Why do you order by a random value? Your SQL query currently doesn't run in SQLPLUS or SQL Developer so there is no chance it would run from ODI.

Comment: n is the number of records I want to select. It could be 2, it could be 10... My sql query is working in sql developer.